# What's the minimum amount of knowledge to start doing research?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, advice

There are cases in which you have too much knowledge of something to do anything interesting ,and cases in which a lack of experience with a problem (and the prejudices about it) helps someone solve it.Therefore,I would like to ask what do you think is minimum amount of knowledge to start doing research? And, is there a balance between too much knowledge and too little?

Comment: I've never been in a situation where I felt like having more knowledge has hurt me, and I think under almost any reasonable set of circumstances it helps.

Comment: Au contraire. If you know a lot about a subject, you also know what are the open problems, and you have some sort of intuition as to how to attack them.

Comment: Perhaps a situation which fits with the OP's question is the bounded gap problem. When Goldston, Pintz, and Yildirim showed in their seminal paper (http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n2-p10-p.pdf) that one can obtain bounded gaps if the level of distribution in the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem can be slightly increased, it was thought that the problem would be intractable for another generation. Yitang Zhang shattered this expectation; most likely because he is an 'outsider'. The later improvements by Maynard are also along these lines.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao : Yitang Zhang was very aware of (and used) all the relevant technical developments in the subject.  He may have been an outsider, but he was hardly a naive amateur.  In any case, this is primarily opinion based, so I've voted to close.

Comment: Here is a possible instance where knowing too much prevents one from being open to certain truths: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/40266/413

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, your example might be about _belief_ impeding one, rather than _knowledge_, ... if we can distinguish these. E.g., belief that "mathematics" (whatever that is) is captured by the formal, orthodox litany of school-mathematics, etc. I'd sincerely claim that school-math, and much cliched formal mathematics, is indeed an excellent approximation of ... something... but can be expected to fail in "edge cases".

Comment: I would argue that the existence of very special cases where people knew too little and had a "new perspective", or people knew "too much" and weren't able to see the forest for the trees does not imply that there is a point at which it becomes optimal to stop gaining new knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Certainly this could turn into an opinion-based something-something, but I suspect that many would agree with the following opinion/observations, which might be helpful to people reading things at this site:

The sort of pop mythology in which "knowing too much" is stultifying, etc. has at least two appeals: first, the romance, second, the possibility that large amounts of preparatory work may be un-necessary. (The "royal road" to mathematics.)

Yes, there is the worthwhile disclaimer that discovery-for-oneself, as opposed to professional research that advances collective understanding, is a good thing. Probably it's good to distinguish discovery-for-oneself from research.

In all examples I know, the issue was not a contrast between "knowing-too-much" and ignorance-based innovation, but whether or not one could assimilate the state of the art without becoming exhausted or disheartened or losing interest. So "talent" is a tolerance for the vastness of what is already known, without it being too much of a burden, without it causing one to be unable to think new thoughts.

Oppositely, unsurprisingly, people who are truly ignorant of what other people've already done invariably reinvent really crappy versions of "the wheel", at best. As discovery-for-self, this is fine, but it's not "research" in a professional sense. Ignorance doesn't help. It's not a good sign if knowledge seems truly burdensome.